# Merge branch DEVELOP into branch master, by date?

Tags: git

I've got 2 branches, branch `DEVELOP` and branch `master`.

I'd like to merge branch `DEVELOP` into branch `master` by date, so all changes up to and including say `Sept 15, 2020 at 4pm`

How can I do this?

Note that the branch `DEVELOP` is not a local branch. It has had many commits by many developers, all pushed to the remote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A branch name is just a convenient way to refer to the last commit in that branch. You can specify any commit to the `git merge` command.

Supposing the branches look like this:

```
A---B---C (master)
         \--D---E---F---G (DEVELOP)
```

and supposing that `E` is the last commit in the date range you want, then from `master` you can run

```
git merge E
```

You probably know this, but for the sake of completeness: you can find the last commit before a certain date by using the `--until` (or `--before`) [option for `git log`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#_commit_limiting). This accepts a wide variety of formats, including exactly what you specified in the question:

```
git log --until="Sept 15, 2020 at 4pm"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can [`cherry-pick`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick) commits by range:

```
git cherry-pick A^..B
```

This will apply the changes from commit `A`, to commit `B` (inclusive).